# Mingw static lib used in a MSVC project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, static-libraries, static-linking

Is it possible to use a static library that was compiled with mingw in a visual studio MSVC project? Both projects are C++. I haven't found a clear answer on that. Note that I'm talking about a static library and not a DLL.

Comment: Mixing and matching with C++ compilers almost never works.  The runtimes/name-mangling rules/etc are usually incompatible.  That said, did you try it?

Comment: Same as [(SO)Can I link object files made by one compile to those made by another one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728116/can-i-link-object-files-made-by-one-compile-to-those-made-by-another-one)

Comment: @Carl: I'm porting a very large project from Linux to Windows and I had partial success compiling it with mingw. I have a hard time compiling it with MSVC. However, our users will link our static library in Visual Studio. So I wanted a clear answer before embarking in a port for mingw.

Comment: @Attila: Thanks for pointing me to that question. When I searched for an answer on StackOverflow, it somehow did not come up in the results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible due to [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for c++ is not standard and `gcc`'s ABI differs from `MSVC++` one.